# How to save the current page (ng-grid) in a parent state?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-grid, angular-ui-router

I have two states (using ui-router) in a parent child relationship.
Each of them is using a directive 'grid', which is encapsulating ng-grid.

The intended workflow is:

1. Begin with parent state
2. Select item (row) in grid
3. click 'next' to get to the child state
4. show a grid with data depending on the selected item in the parent state
5. Go back (browser back button)
6. Select another item and repeat steps 3-5

Now the problem is, that I'm using paging in ng-grid and therefore I want to remember the current page in the parent state when coming back to it. Since the $scope of the parent state is being destroyed I considered the following approaches:

1. Store it in the URL: Not a option because I don't want the browser's back and forth buttons to trigger paging changes.
2. Store it in the child as custom data property: Bad because I want to use the child in a encapsulated way (you can also reach the child state by not coming from a grid). Also since it is a property of the parent state this really doesn't "feel good"!

I'm kinda stuck here, any ideas for clean approaches?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Store the current page in a service. Angular services persist through controller creation and destruction.